# Working CAS, now not working after replacing SHA1 certificate with sha256

Tags: ssl-certificate, cas, sha

We had a perfectly working CAS (4.0) when we replaced an SSL cert with SHA1 encryption to SHA256.

We installed the cert and the new CA chain into the cacerts file.  The subject (CN and all)  are identical.

I go to my CAS protected site, I am correctly redirected to CAS, I can log in, and I get redirected to my site,  but at that point I am redirected back to CAS, which thinks I am logged in...  and endless loop.

Like I said, this was a perfectly working CAS before.  Here is the relevant log:

```
FINE: Attempting to retrieve ticket [TGT-2-d7Z3hwQdJl4jWt0ZW1xCewqjgcdxxaCvIWzIvxueYcPJTuKXmN-XX.XX.XX.XX]
Jul 27, 2016 6:19:06 PM org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry getTicket
FINE: Ticket [TGT-2-d7Z3hwQdJl4jWt0ZW1xCewqjgcdxxaCvIWzIvxueYcPJTuKXmN-XX.XX.XX.XX] found in registry.
Jul 27, 2016 6:19:06 PM org.jasig.cas.web.flow.TerminateWebSessionListener sessionEnded
FINE: Terminate web session pC0up4YeyUpNO_e_CD_6NyJxMSq752luD8i9d3b8pZO_wR6Q9g3-!325246342!1469661546014 in 2 seconds
```

You can see it finds the ticket in the registry,  but then terminates the session.

There are no errors or exceptions in the logs at all.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at the logs, and I will see that the service ticket has expired. Turns out,  the bump from SHA-1 to SHA256  made the network trip from 6 seconds 13 seconds, and the TTL for the service ticket expired.